# I am having problems with what seems like a simple regex to delete lines with sed

Tags: regex, sed

When I `grep` with `^[0-9{7}]*` it detects all the lines I need. But when I run this it just deletes everything.

I cannot find a reference for properly escaping the sed command. I know this is an RTFM moment as well :(

`sed '/^[0-9{7}]*/d' simple.txt`

```
4216333 2018-06-11T17:27:16-0500    446421648264    140843
4153130 2018-06-11T17:27:15-0500    446421650974    142398
4154997 2018-06-11T17:27:15-0500    446421650985    142399
4155087 2018-06-11T17:27:15-0500    446421650996    142400
4155543 2018-06-11T17:27:15-0500    446421651000    142401
4155615 2018-06-11T17:27:15-0500    446421651010    142402
4155650 2018-06-11T17:27:15-0500    446421651021    142403
4155681 2018-06-11T17:27:14-0500    446421651032    142404
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `^[0-9{7}]*` pattern matches a line that starts with 0 or more digits, `{`, or `}` chars. Thus, it matches any line.

To delete lines that start with 7 digits you may use the following POSIX BRE based sed command:

```
sed '/^[0-9]\{7\}/d' simple.txt
```

Or, with a POSIX ERE pattern (where the `{x}` quantifier does not require escaping):

```
sed -E '/^[0-9]{7}/d' simple.txt
```

Note that in case you want to omit all lines where the first non-whitespace chunk is not equal to 7 digits, it is more convenient to use `awk`:

```
awk '$1 !~ /^[0-9]{7}$/' simple.txt
```

With `sed` (BRE POSIX, no `-E` option), it will look like `/^[0-9]\{7\}[[:blank:]]/d`, `/^[0-9]\{7\}[[:space:]]/d`, `/^[0-9]\{7\}\>/d`, `/^[0-9]\{7\}\b/d`.

Comment: I guess my question should be changed. I am curious where you found all of this information? Are there resources to know what command in `sed` should be escaped? Thank you for this.

Comment: @CGSmith105 Excuse me, what should be changed? Judging by the current question, you misunderstand how to code sequences of patterns. Putting all inside square brackets may lead to a pattern error or will just match a single char belonging to the set.

Comment: Nothing should be changed. How did you learn what characters to escape?

Comment: @CGSmith105 [Here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html) is a good article about the BRE and ERE difference.